# Are react state variable accessible (globally) in production build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As the question states.

I mean, say webpack renames a state variable `foo` (declared with useState) of a component to `a.b.c`. Can someone open the console in browser (post build) and run a `console.log(a.b.c)`, or are they protected inside a context.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the point is to restrict access to certain sensitive data, it shouldn't be in your state in the first place. Whatever is accessible to the browser is accessible to the user.

Comment: What would be the correct way to store, say an access token?

Comment: Right off the top of my head, you may place API proxy between the client and API (you want to secure access to). The other way around, if you're using server-side rendering, you may perform API data fetching at the server.